# How to change class only in specified area on JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I have a table with some `td` elements with the same class. But i want to change claas only in specified area `.selected`.

I make this:

```
<tr>
<td>--</td>
<td class="mcost"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="selected">
<td><input type="radio" name="work" onclick="selone('.selected','#sel1','m');" checked="checked" /></td>
<td id="sel1" class="mcost"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="selected">
<td><input type="radio" name="work" onclick="selone('.selected','#sel2','m');" /></td>
<td id="sel2" class="mcost"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>--</td>
<td class="mcost"></td>
</tr>
```

And try this:

```
function selone(g,f,n){
    $(g).each(function(){
        $('.'+n+'cost').removeClass().addClass(n+'cost_dis');
    });
    $(f).removeClass().addClass(n+'cost');
}
```

But it's change class to all mcost elements =( Not only in specified area. How to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your .each, you requery the entire dom for .mcost cells. You need to do the following:

```
function selone(g,f,n){
    $(g).each(function(){
        $(this).find('.'+n+'cost').removeClass().addClass(n+'cost_dis');
    });
    $(f).removeClass().addClass(n+'cost');
}
```

This will only change the .mcost items inside of your $(g) element. This should work. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a better, and unobtrusive approach:

1. remove the onclick-events in the html.
2. Use the script to this:

   $(function () {
       $(".selected :radio").click(function () {
           var selected = $(this).parents(".selected:first");
           selected.removeClass().addClass('mcost_dis');
           selected.find('.mcost').removeClass().addClass('mcost');
       });
   });

(However the last line doesn't add much)

*The problem is in the part `$('.'+n+'cost')`
this does not consider the context it is called in. It will allways select all `.mcost` elements in the page.
if you change it to:
    $(this).find('.'+n+'cost')
it will search only in the context of g. Do the same for f.
However, it all depends on what g and f are. Using `.selected` in this case it should give you what you want.*

Comment: In your example it change to both td elements, but i need only to one (by id).

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".selected td").each( function() { $(this).addClass("whatever"); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the `each` loop at all if you change your selector a bit. Wouldn't this work:

```
function selone(g,f,n) {
   // find elements that already have the class, and change them
   $(g + " ." + n + 'cost').removeClass().addClass(n+'cost_dis');

   // add class to newly selected item
   $(f).removeClass().addClass(n + 'cost');
}
```

Assuming you call it with

```
selone('.selected','#sel1','m');
```

Then within the function `$(g + " ." + n + 'cost')` evaluates as `$(".selected .mcost")` - which means "find elements of class 'mcost' that are descendents of elements with class 'selected'".